# Using ReasonML FFI

Tags: ffi, reason, bucklescript

I'm trying to understand ReasonML's FFI (i.e. `external`) usage. To that end, I put together the following code (see [Try ReasonML](https://reasonml.github.io/try?rrjsx=true&reason=C4TwDgpgBAJg9gWwNwChSShANhBEB2wqA2gAIBGAzgHQBuAhlgLpQoQAewEATvo7IgBcAhFAC8UAETwAxgFc8hSSQo1KBGNTABLDMPgImbTjz5YoAcwjAA%20uRA3tMYZWDdt%20C%20IB8mHIuBxKStgAFF-AmAAIRAASRhlFBxA4HovCVkFSKgAH18QuwcnAApJBHoPSQBKJCA) and [Sketch.sh](https://sketch.sh/s/yX1Pj8DhgQ6HqKTd84q60w/))

```
type dom;
type element;
[@bs.val] 
external dom: dom = "document";
[@bs.send.pipe : dom]
external get_by_id: string => element = "getElementById";
let tag = document |> get_by_id("main");
```

However, the code currently fails with the errors:

**Try ReasonML Error**

> We've found a bug for you! OCaml preview 6:11-18
>
> The value document can't be found

**Sketch.sh Error**

> Error: External identifiers must be functions

Would appreciate help in answering the following questions:

1. What are the issues with the code above?
2. I believe there are multiple ways to configure the FFI above, e.g. using `[@bs.scope]` - what implications, if any, are there from those ways? -- [See follow-up question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002630/what-are-the-implications-of-different-reasonml-external-declarations)

Comment: I've answered the first question below. But you should not ask multiple questions in a single post. See [ask]. I suggest instead that you post the second question as a separate post where you show concrete examples so we also don't have to guess at what you're referring to.

Comment: Fair enough; I originally included both questions since I believed the two were meaningfully connected. Updated original post to link to follow-up question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different problems here:

1. You use an identifier called `document` in the last line, but have not defined any such identifier. Instead you have assigned the name `dom` to reference `document` on the JavaScript side. The last line should therefore be `let tag = dom |> get_by_id("main");`.
2. This will unfortunately still not work in "Try Reason", however, because it runs the code in a Web Worker which does not have access to `document`.
3. Sketch.sh does not use BuckleScript and therefore does not understand BuckleScript FFI annotations. You can however use https://nit.sketch.sh/, which does.