# What are the Implications of Different ReasonML External Declarations?

Tags: ffi, reason, bucklescript

In the examples below, both external declarations achieve the *same* functionality with slightly different ReasonML function structures.

Does external declaration *style* impact anything (e.g. performance) beyond ReasonML function structure? Also, does ReasonML have a "suggested" external declaration "style"?

**Type Declarations**

```
type dom;
type element;
```

---

**External Declaration Style 1**

```
[@bs.val] 
external dom: dom = "document";
[@bs.send.pipe : dom]
external get_by_id: string => element = "getElementById";
```

---

**External Declaration Style 2**

```
[@bs.scope "document"] [@bs.val]
external by_id: string => element = "getElementById";
```

---

**ReasonML Function Calls**

```
let tag1 = dom |> get_by_id("main");
let tag2 = by_id("main")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference should be apparent from how they're used.

```rust
let tag1 = dom |> get_by_id("main"); // has two parts
let tag2 = by_id("main") // has only one part
```

Having two parts means you can swap each part out with other parts, as long as they  have the same type signature. We could for example replace `dom` (the value) with a different instance of `dom` (the type):

```rust
[@bs.new]
external make_doc: unit => dom = "Document";

let tag3 = make_doc() |> get_by_id("main");
```

There's also a more subtle implication to this, however. Having two parts means you can evaluate the parts in different contexts. This isn't as easy to illustrate, but consider this contrived example:

```rust
[@bs.val] 
external dom: dom = "document";

let dom1 = dom;

[%%raw {|var document = null|}];

let dom2 = dom;

let tag1 = dom1 |> get_by_id("main");
let tag2 = dom2 |> get_by_id("main");
let tag3 = by_id("main")
```

`dom1` and `dom2` here refer to different values. Using `dom1` will work as expected, while using `dom2` will crash. As will `by_id`.

So which should you use? Well, that depends on what you need. If you will always use the `document` currently in scope, use `bs.scope` since that's more convenient. If you don't, or you want to use the same function with several different values, use `@bs.send`/`@bs.send.pipe`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and helpful answer. Minor point, `document` is misspelled in raw declaration.

Comment: @Ari: Oops, fixed :)